# set headers of webview by loadDataWithBaseURL

Tags: android, webview, header

Is there a way to set headers of webview when using loadDataWithBaseURL method on webview?

I know there is loadUrl method to set it , But I need loadDataWithBaseURL method to use.
Any help will be appreciated.